# get mouse coordinates relative to a div position doesn't work in firefox

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't the example code below work in my browser, firefox v. 19.0.2?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#example {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 50px;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background-color: #C00;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$("#example").mousemove(function(e) {
var xPos = e.pageX - $(this).position().left;
var yPos = e.pageY - $(this).position().top;
$("#pos").text("x: " + xPos + " / y: " + yPos);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example"></div>
<div id="pos"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't see the coordinates that are supposed to be in the `<div>` tag with ID pos.
ThanX in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You're attaching the event handler when the element isn't present in the DOM yet.
Wrap your JavaScript in an [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example").mousemove(function(e) {
        var xPos = e.pageX - $(this).position().left;
        var yPos = e.pageY - $(this).position().top;
        $("#pos").text("x: " + xPos + " / y: " + yPos);
    }); 
});
```